# Xml Generation from Google test does not show skipped test cases

Tags: xml, googletest

I am using google test framework for doing unit testing in c++. I have few test cases which i have disabled using DISABLED_ before test name and some tests are skipped using GTEST_SKIP(). This is working fine and i can see the tests being disabled and skipped in the teminal log. The problem is when i am generating the xml file from the test.
I am using the following command.

```
--gtest_output=xml:/data/TestReport.xml
```

The generated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="17" failures="7" disabled="3" errors="0" time="57.713" timestamp="1970-01-04T10:31:55" name="AllTests">
<testsuite name="UNITTEST" tests="17" failures="7" disabled="3" errors="0" time="45.713" timestamp="1970-01-04T10:32:04">
<testcase name="Test_1" status="run" result="skipped" time="0" timestamp="1970-01-04T10:32:04" classname="UNITTEST" />
<testcase name="Test_2" status="run" result="completed" time="0.461" timestamp="1970-01-04T10:32:04" classname="UNITTEST" />
<testcase name="Test_3" status="run" result="completed" time="7.089" timestamp="1970-01-04T10:32:05" classname="UNITTEST">
```

I would like to point out that the tag testsuites which is a consolidation of all the testsuite does not have an attribute skipped.
The tag testsuite which is a consolidation of all the tests also does not have the attribute skipped. However, the test Test_1 does show the result as skipped. Is there any configuration to make the count of skipped appear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a version issue. I'm gussing it was added [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/2767). The tag `testsuite` has `skipped` for me:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="3" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0" timestamp="2022-05-13T17:38:54.980" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="MyTestSuite" tests="3" failures="0" disabled="0" skipped="1" errors="0" time="0" timestamp="2022-05-13T17:38:54.980">
    <testcase name="Test1" status="run" result="skipped" time="0" timestamp="2022-05-13T17:38:54.980" classname="MyTestSuite">
      <skipped message="tests/gtest_demo/fib_test.cc:10&#x0A;"><![CDATA[tests/gtest_demo/fib_test.cc:10
]]></skipped>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Test2" status="run" result="completed" time="0" timestamp="2022-05-13T17:38:54.981" classname="MyTestSuite" />
    <testcase name="Test3" status="run" result="completed" time="0" timestamp="2022-05-13T17:38:54.981" classname="MyTestSuite" />
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

This is the example that I ran: https://godbolt.org/z/9aW7GrYfj

Make sure you are running the latest release.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I really appreciate that you also added the link to the PR where it was added. However, the tag testsuites which shows the consolidation of all the test suites still doesn't show the attribute skipped(alsoin the xml that you attached). Is it an expected behavior?

Comment: I don't think that is intentional. Looks like they added it for `testsuite` but missed it for `testsuites`. I would file this as a bug on Google Test github.

Comment: I have reported it. https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/3836